# Storing structured and unstructured data

Tags: database, structured-data

I working on web application that require to store structured information like user information and unstructured information corresponding to the user.
My question is whether I should use two different databases for storing structured and unstructured data.  Any thoughts will be helpful.

Answer (score 0):

It depends on each concrete usecase.
Generally if there are no security or other constraints, store the information together. You can use a document oriented database e.g. MongoDB, where the unstructured information can be stored as value of property "unstructured" of the document.
If you prefer a relational database e.g. Oracle, then the unstructured information can be stored as VARCHAR2, CLOB or BLOB column value.